# web service for a physical device, which technology/protocols to use?

Tags: web-services, device

(Please note that I am self-learning beginner)

I am developing a web server for a device that to be connected in a network. Its services will mostly be used in local large networks, not on Internet.

To be specific, the device is an Under Vehicle Inspection System (UVIS), that records video when vehicles pass and do some processing with it, then it will send it to a connected authorized local client to view and to a database (i.e. event based system).

First, I have searched for technology/protocols used by printer web services (network printers), and found that there are specific protocols for printers, and some are even specific to some manufacturers.

I came across the WS-* stack, (actually I have made a simple implementation for discovering IP-cameras using WS-Discovery and used SOAP with some functions defined by Onvif specifications), but I found this complex and not sure if it worth taking the risk of delving in this world. A little search about this revealed that this mostly used by windows systems (actually Microsoft is a major developer for these standards).

I am looking for other off-the-shelf technology/protocols, that has discovery features, simple to implement, integrable with other devices, wide-spread and future proof.

**Can someone enlighten me on this?**

Until now my plan is to use WS-Discovery (as it has IANA-reserved multi-cast address) to get a Websocket uri, and implement a simple protocol of my own on that. I chose websocket over normal socket as it has a chance to be used with browser applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're recording video, you either want to stream it in real time (look at RTSP protocol that the high-end IP cameras use, implementations can be found in gstreamer or vlc), or if you're pulling the video after its been recorded as a file then just use a normal web upload system.

Chances are your camera that records the video could be sending the data feed as RTSP anyway, so you might just need to connect to that feed.

I would use a web protocols these days anyway, no need to reinvent the wheel. There are many webservers for embedded systems (open source civetweb comes to mind as something very simple and effective). Then you're creating your program using established, common web services. Easy to build and well understood by practically everyone.

WS-* protocols are complex, if you can't get a lib working, then it might be a lot less painful just to register a server service in the network's DNS and let each client tell it (via a REST API call)) what its current IP address is. It would be even easier to have each device be registered with the networks' DNS server from the start though, to discover which are available you just need to ping each one then.

Comment: can I host a local DNS on the device? is there any practical limitations regarding the nature of networks in e.g. enterprises? (let aside the limitations of the device itself)

Comment: I suppose you can, but there's no point - DNS is for a central repository on the network, so whatever network they are connected to should host the DNS. How do they get their IP address? DHCP? Statically assigned?

Comment: I assume if it is statically assigned there won't be a problem, just ask the IT department to give me a local IP. But if DHCP I assume they should make an entry in a DNS (edit: or may give me static IP as well), am I right? but what if the network is using a gateway which may use a public DNS and no local DNS? can this happen?

Comment: You can't have a public DNS on a closed local LAN. If the LAN has access to a  DNS, then you have access to the same DNS (obviously). Lot of assumptions there, I can't answer "what ifs".